# How to fit an element to screen in my case

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a complex issue that needs you guys help.

I have a very large image and have several image map link on it.

When I click the image link, I want to show a new div with images and contents on it and transform from a very small element to fit the browser screen (overlay the original page). I have created my codes and files but not sure how to do the fit to screen feature. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot.

http://jsfiddle.net/kB27M/5/

Please click '`overside load`' flag in my jsfiddle image. then you will see a image pop and resize. I need to make sure it resize to 100% of my browser window. Thanks!

Comment: FYI doesn't work in Firefox for me

Comment: did you try height:100% and width:100%? or is that not what you want. in that case please describe what you want because it's not that clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of removing some code and adding other,
To get window size you can use the jquery method `width()` on `window` object, same to `height()`;

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

Putting it together, the new `div` you want with window size will need to be set like this:

```
$(contentDiv).width($(window).width());
$(contentDiv).height($(window).height());
```

Now you want to put it to overlay the window, you can easily achieve it with a css trick by setting its `position` as `fixed` so mouse scroll won't affect it:

```
$(contentDiv).css("position","fixed");
$(contentDiv).css({top:0, left:0});
```

Check this out

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kB27M/11/)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was hoping see the resize effect starting from where the 'oversize load' link instead of from top left corner. Can you make some adjustments? +1

Comment: I'm not sure how that animation would work but looks like we would need to get `scroll` offset, sounds like a challenge hehe